# Change gitlab repository location

Tags: gitlab, digital-ocean

I'm running Gitlab 8.9.4 CE Omnibus on Ubuntu server 14.04 a DigitalOcean droplet with a block storage volume formatted and mounted at `/mnt/volume-fra1-01-part1` I have created a subdirectory `git-data` (0755 git:git) on the volume and I want Gitlab to use that as its git repository location.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/configuration.md#storing-git-data-in-an-alternative-directory) to update the Ruby variable, but changing it and running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` has no effect. My `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file looks like this:

```
external_url "<my URL here>"

git_data_dirs({"default" => "/mnt/volume-fra1-01-part1/git-data"})

gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['lfs_storage_path'] = "/mnt/volume-fra1-01-part1/gitlab-lfs-objects"
```

The git LFS settings work OK, so it definitely reads the config file.

Any ideas what I might have missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar case just recently. I am using Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS and my hard-driver is mounted under /mnt/sdb.

**sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure** gave me permission error.

I used the following command and it fixed the issue:
**sudo chmod 755 /mnt/sdb**

Here are the complete steps:

1. sudo gedit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb -> git_data_dirs({"default" => "/mnt/sdb/gitlab/git-data"})
2. sudo chmod 755 /mnt/sdb
3. sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
4. sudo gitlab-ctl stop
5. sudo rsync -av /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories /mnt/sdb/gitlab/git-data/
6. sudo gitlab-ctl upgrade
7. sudo ls -l /mnt/sdb/gitlab/git-data/
8. sudo gitlab-ctl start

Hope that helps.